# Linking error in MSVC 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I have a file structure like this:

file1.h

```
extern const char *build_info[][3];
```

file1.cpp

```
    #include "file1.h"

    const char *build_info[][3] = {
       { "abc", "de", "feg" },
       { ... }, 
        ...
        };
```

file2.cpp

```
// Use build_info
```

Now I am getting this erro under MSVC 2008 Express

```
file2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * (* build_info)[3]"
```

Looks like I am not able to link file1.obj. Any idea how I can verify:

- Whether the obj is linked.
- It has the symbol defined.

Comment: Would it matter is the files were file1 was .c(not .cpp) and file2 was .cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem, file1.cpp was actually file.c. Only I enclosed that in

```
extern C { .. }
```

it is working fine.